# My tablet lines keep breaking up

Tags: tablet

im using an intuos pen & touch small and when i draw the lines will break up randomly no matter how hard i press, its very sporadic. i have tried re-installing my driver multiple of times, i have tried using my tablet on another computer. also i changing my nibs multiple times. this has been happenening in all programs i have tried it with. (paint tool sai, clip studio paint)

heres an image of whats happening : [image]

i didnt pick up my pen at all during the stroke.

Comment: Are you drawing really fast? Does it happen when you go slow? You may need to contact Wacom support for this. I don't think anyone here can troubleshoot hardware and it's not *really* on topic.

Comment: it happens no matter what speed i am drawing at?

Comment: This is not a design question but a hardware question.  I think you would get better answers on SuperUser so I have migrated your question.

Comment: If multiple stylus pens present this problem then its likely the screen on the `intuos` itself is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your pen is broken. As you draw, it detects button presses from side buttons and thus breaking in the line.

So far I haven't found permanent fix to it. Hitting it against desk seems to help sometimes, but I wouldn't recommend this solutiotion.